# I am having trouble converting integer to string

Tags: c#, integer

```
namespace C2360_Ch07_Console1_InRange
{
    class InRange
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           

            Console.WriteLine("Num:");

            String theLine;
            theLine = Console.ReadLine();

            
            try
            {
                theLine = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());//cant convert

            }

            catch (FormatException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Input string was not in a correct format.");
            }

            IsWithinRange(theLine);
        }

        static void IsWithinRange(String theLine)
        {
            int Line1;
            Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out Line1);

            try
            {

                if ((Line1 < 1) || (Line1 > 10))
                {
                    throw new OverflowException();

                }

            }
            catch (OverflowException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("number must be between 1 and 10.");
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }

}
```

What im trying to do is to *convert* `string` to `int`eger to validate `Main` and `IsWithinRange` method. I get an **error**, where the comment is at, when I convert `theLine` to `Int32.TryParse`. Is this *ever possible*?
Anything would help?

Comment: Are you sure the error is at Int32.TryParse and not at Convert.ToInt32 before?

Comment: the error is at Convert.ToInt32 why?

Comment: My guess is you're typing a number, then hitting Enter again as nothing is happening: this is because you're calling `Console.ReadLine()` **twice** for `theLine`

Comment: sorry about that she wants us to String theLine;
theLine = Console.ReadLine();

in Main. Then pass theLine to the Convert.Int32 in Main. You will need to make IsWithinRange have a String parameter. Pass theLine to that function when you call it from Main. And then you can use that string parameter when you call TryParse in IsWithinRange.

Comment: First you're setting `theLine` to be a  string - `String theLine = Console.ReadLine();`. Then, you're trying to set it to be an integer by calling ReadLine again - `theLine = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine())'.

Comment: This of course won't compile..

Answer (score 2):

I suggest *extracting a method* for reading integer value:

```
   private static int ReadInteger(string title) {
       while (true) {
           Console.WriteLine(title);

           if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int result))
               return result;

           Console.WriteLine("Incorrect syntax. Please, try again");
       }
   }
```

And then use it:

```
   static void Main(string[] args) {
       int theLine = 0;

       while (true) { 
         theLine = ReadInteger("Num:");

         // theLine is an integer, but we want an extra conditions meet:  
         if (theLine >= 1 && theLine <= 10)
           break;

         Console.WriteLine("The value must be in [1..10] range. Please, try again"); 
       }

       // from now on theLine is an integer in [1..10] range 
       //TODO: put relevant code here
   }
```

Please, note, that *exceptions* `FormatException`, `OverflowException` are for *exceptional behavior*; here (user input validation), good old `if` is enough.

**Edit:** If you don't want to extract method (why?) but preserve `IsWithinRange` you can put something like this:

```
   static void Main(string[] args) {
       int theLine = 0;

       while (true) {
           Console.WriteLine("Num:");

           if (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out theLine)) {
               Console.WriteLine("Syntax error. Please, try again");

               continue;
           } 

           if (IsWithinRange(theLine))
               break;

           Console.WriteLine("Sorry, the value is out of range. Please, try again"); 
       }
       // from now on theLine is an integer in [1..10] range 
       //TODO: put relevant code here
```

Where `IsWithinRange` can be

```
   // Least Confusion Principle: For "Is [the value] Within Range" question
   // the expected answer is either true or false
   private static bool IsWithinRange(int value) {
       return value >= 1 && value <= 10;
   }
```

Comment: Dmitry Bychenko, thats not the way she wants it. she wants just the main and iswithinrange.